# How come two Strings are not equals when they print the same thing?

Tags: java

this may be a silly question but I honestly have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I created a class that reads a file and prints every words in it. First I created an instance of my class called 'lines'. I ran my program to see what lines.toString() prints, and then copy/pasted the result. I stored the result in a String variable called 'result' and then I compared 'result' and 'lines'.

As it turns out, lines.equals(result) is false.. Why is this? I only copy and pasted the result and then compare it to the original. They literally print the same thing, so there should be no difference in white space or anything like that. I know its a bit long, but my code is below if you would like to take a look at it. I appreciate anyone who would help me. Thank you!

```
public Document(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file;
    Scanner docScanner;

    String curLine;
    numLines = 0;
    numWords = 0;

    file = new File(fileName);
    docScanner = new Scanner(file);

    while (docScanner.hasNext()) {
        docScanner.nextLine();
        numLines++;
    }

    docScanner = new Scanner(file);
    words = new String[numLines][];

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        curLine = docScanner.nextLine();
        words[i] = curLine.trim().split("\\s");

        if (words[i][0].equals("")) {
            words[i] = new String[0];
        } else {
            for (int j = 0; j < words[i].length; j++) {
                numWords++;
            }
        }
    }
}

public String getLine(int lineNum) throws NoSuchLineException {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < words[lineNum].length; i++) {
        result = result + words[lineNum][i] + " ";
    }
    return result;  
}

public String toString() {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        result = result + getLine(i) + "\n";
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Document lines = new Document("file.txt");

    String result = "Mary had \r\n" + 
            "a little lamb \r\n" + 
            "Its fleece was \r\n" + 
            "white \r\n" + 
            "as snow ";

    if (lines.toString().equals(result)) {
        System.out.println("They are equal");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not equal");
    }
}

file.txt is below:
Mary had 
        a little lamb
Its fleece was 
    white 
as snow
```

Comment: String equality works between strings using '.equals()' however, you seem to be comparing a 'Document' object with a 'String' object.

e.g.
`
String a = "abc";
String b = "abc";
String c = "def";
System.out.println(a.equals(b));
System.out.println(a.equals(c));
`

Comment: You're confused about what `.equals` does. For two objects to be considered equal they need to be of the same type.

Comment: I changed 'lines' to lines.toString(). I think the question should make sense now

Comment: It seems the cause of the problem is your `toString` method: in line `result = result + getLine(i) + "\n";` you are always appending the newline regardless if you're at the last line - you don't have this last newline character inside your `result` variable

Comment: @KamilPiwowarski thank you very much! that makes more sense!

Comment: @KamilPiwowarski Now that the nature of the Question has been changed, I suggest you make an Answer of your Comment.

Comment: You should take much more care before posting to Stack Overflow. Your change in code example completely changes the nature of this Question, making my Answer look nonsensical now, and wasting people's time.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (lines.equals(result)) {
```

`lines` is a `Document`, while `result` is a [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html).

So they cannot be equal. Comparing `Document` and `String` is like comparing [apples and oranges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apples_and_oranges).

I do not know what class is `Document`, as you neglected to mention.

Regarding `String`, its [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method requires an object of the same class. To quote the documentation:

> Compares this string to the specified object. The result is `true` if and only if the argument is not null and is a `String` object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

Comment: "Regarding String, its equals method requires an object of the same class." - I don't think that's technically true.

Comment: @TeWu How do you interpret "…and is a String object…" in the Javadoc quoted above?

Comment: I apologize, it should be if (lines.toString().equals(result)). So now theyre both strings. However, they are still not equal.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment section: rewriting my comment as an answer.

It seems the cause of the problem is inside implementation of the `toString` method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    result = result + getLine(i) + "\n";
}
```

Newline character is always appened, regardless if in the middle of the loop, or at the last line, while the test string lacks the newline character in the last line.

Taking this into account, the for loop could look something like:

```
public String toString() {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
        result = result + getLine(i)+"\r\n";
    }
    return result + getLine(words.length - 1);
}
```

Please note I've also changed unix line ending `\n` into windows equivalent `\r\n` you used in the `result` String in the sample, as those are not equal.

In most cases it is better to use `System.lineSeparator()` method instead of manually writing the separator in the string as under various circumstances your strings could be wrongly displayed on different systems if you use the wrong one.

My version of the loop can of course be further improved, for example by introducing a variable in place of `words.length - 1` for better readability, and more importantly: usage of [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) instance initialized before start of the loop instead of String for the concatenation.